# How to access "this" reference of anonymous outer class in java

Tags: java, closures, anonymous-types

I have the following problem. Two nested anonymous types. I want to access "this" reference of the outer anonymous class inside the most inner class. Usually if one has anonymous nested class in a named outer class (lets call it "class Outer") he/she would type inside the nested class `Outer.this.someMethod()`. How do I refer the outer class if it's anonymous ?
Example Code:

```
public interface Outer {
    void outerMethod();
}

public interface Inner {
    void innerMethod();
}
...
public static void main(String[] args) {
...
new Outer() {
    public void outerMethod() {
        new Inner() {
            public void innerMethod() {
                Outer.this.hashCode(); // this does not work
            } // innerMethod
        }; // Inner
    } // outerMethod
}; // Outer
...
} // main
```

The error I get is

> No enclosing instance of the type Outer is accessible in scope

I know that I can copy the reference like this:

```
final Outer outerThisCopy = this;
```

just before instantiating the `Inner` object and then refer to this variable. The real goal is that I want to compare the hashCodes of `outerThisCopy` and the object accessed inside the `new Inner` object (i.e the `Outer.this`) for debugging purposes. I have some good arguments to think that this two objects are different (in my case).
[Context: The argument is that calling a getter implemented in the "Outer" class which is not shadowed in the "Inner" class returns different objects]

Any ideas how do I access the "this" reference of the enclosing anonymous type ?

Thank you.

Comment: You could provide a method `int outerHashCode() { return hashCode(); }` in your anonymous outer class. In your inner class, you have access to this method; just call it. I fear, another approach is not possible.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot access an instance of anonymous class directly from inner class or another anonymous class inside it, since the anonymous class doesn't have a name. However, you can get a reference to the outer class via a method:

```
new Outer()
{
    public Outer getOuter()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public void outerMethod()
    {
        new Inner()
        {
            public void innerMethod()
            {
                getOuter().hashCode();
            }
        };
    }
};
```